# Security issues with Itsdangerous for session management?

Tags: python, security, session, cryptography, client-side

The content of a signed cookie with Itsdangerous can be inspected but not altered. 
Are there any known security issues or considerations when using [Itsdangerous](http://packages.python.org/itsdangerous/) for client side session management?

The session in question will not store any passwords, but obviously some information to identify the user, such as

- User ID
- URL to avatar
- User role(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using a timeout on your signature, an attacker could simply swap out the cookie from another user (or admin). Session IDs are more opaque, meaning that an attacker would need to try each one in turn, but a signed string could just be inspected on the fly (on say, an open proxy server).

Comment: In one approach to REST API endpoints the signed string is provided by the server on login with a password and is then sent on each request together with the User ID and has an expiry period of, say, X hours. The signed string is also stored on the server. On logout the string is expunged from the server. That way the string (token) functions as a temporary password for 2 hours (or less if there is a logout).